# Identing a map from a yaml template in terraform

Tags: dictionary, yaml, label, terraform, indentation

I am in Terraform 14 and I am trying to add labels to my template file which should generate a YAML:

Template File:

```
labels:
  ${labels}
```

Code:

```
locals {
 labels = merge(
   var.labels,
   map(
    "module", basename(abspath(path.module)),
    "module_version", var.module_version
   )
 )
prometheus_config      = templatefile("${path.module}/prometheus.tmpl", {
   labels                 = indent(8, yamlencode(local.labels))
})
```

When I try to add the labels indenting with 8 this outputs in the template file causing YAML errors:

Error Output:

```
labels:
  "module": "my_module"
    "module_version": "1.0"
```

As you can see the module_version has indent 8 which is correct but the module line is not indented.

I tried many things like moving `${labels}` everywhere in the beginning, with multiple indentations but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

It is for this reason that [the `templatefile` documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) recommends [using `yamlencode` for the entire data structure](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html#generating-json-or-yaml-from-a-template), rather than trying to concantenate bits of YAML together using just string templates. That way the `yamlencode` function can guarantee you a correctly-formatted result and you only have to produce a suitable data structure:

In your case, that would involve replacing the template contents with the following:

```
${yamlencode({
  labels = labels
})}
```

...and then replacing the prometheus_config definition with the following:

```
locals {
  prometheus_config = templatefile("${path.module}/prometheus.tmpl", {
    labels = local.labels
  })
}
```

Notice that the `yamlencode` call is now *inside* the template, and it covers the entire YAML document rather than just a fragment of it.

With a simple test configuration I put together with some hard-coded values for the variables you didn't show, I got the following value for `local.prometheus_config`:

```
"labels":
  "module": "example"
  "module_version": "1.0"
```

---

If this was a full example of the YAML you are aiming to generate then I might also consider simplifying but just inlining the `yamlencode` call directly inside the local value definition, and not have the separate template file at all:

```
locals {
  prometheus_config = yamlencode({
    labels = local.labels
  })
}
```

If the real YAML is much larger or is likely to grow larger later then I'd probably still keep that `templatefile` call, but I just wanted to note this for completeness, since there's more than one way to get this done.

Comment: Didn't work. It produced the wrong indentation between labels & module_name. The module_name is one level before labels which makes yaml to break

Comment: I've added to my answer the result I saw when I tried what I suggested. Did you get a different result? or if not, is the result I got different than what you need?

Answer (score 0):

So using terraform 14 I was not able to transform lists or maps into yaml with `yamlencode`. Every option I tried using the suggested answer produced  results with the wrong **indentation**. Maybe due to the many indentation levels in the file... I am not sure. So I dropped the use of `yamlencode` in the solution.

**Solution:**

I decided to use inline solution so for lists I transform then with string with `join` and for maps I use `jsonencode` so:

```
# var.list is a list in terraform
# local.abels is a map in terraform

thanos_config = templatefile("${path.module}/thanos.tmpl", {
  urls   = join(",", var.list), 
  labels = jsonencode(local.labels)
})
```

The resulting plan output is a bit ugly but it works.